# Show related product for perticular Pincode using service provider in angular2

Tags: html, angular

I want to create a single page application without use of routing,that will show when i give input for pincode,it will show the product for that pincode using service and injection.i am a bit confuse to create it.

Here is my product.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './product';

@Injectable()

export class ProductService {

private products: Product[] = [
new Product('10', 'schezwan rice', 'with schezwan sauce tasty',  'http://www.foodinnrestaurant.com/images/stories/virtuemart/product/prodt_328.jpg'),

Product('11', 'Summer salad', 'looks tasty and healthy', 'http://images.media- allrecipes.com/userphotos/250x250/00/39/70/397065.jpg')
];

constructor() { }

getProducts() {
return this.products;
}

}
```

I make a class for product
In product.ts

```
   export class Product {

constructor (public pin: number, public name: string, public description: string, public imagePath: string) {

}

}
```

Here is my product-group component

```
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12">

<ul class="list-group">

<li *ngFor="let product of products" [product]="product"(click)="onSelected(product)"></li>
 </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
```

here is my product-group.ts code

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
 import { Product } from '../product';


@Component({
selector: 'ps-product-group',
templateUrl: './product-group.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./product-group.component.css']
})
export class ProductGroupComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() product: Product;
constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {

}


 }
```

Here is my pincode.ts code

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../product';
import { ProductService } from '../product.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'ps-pincode',
 templateUrl: './pincode.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pincode.component.css'],
  providers: [ProductService]

})
export class PincodeComponent implements OnInit {
  products: Product[] =[];
  @Output() productSelected = new EventEmitter<Product>();

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSelected(product: Product) {
  this.productSelected.emit(product);
  }

  }
```

here is my pincode html component

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your   pincode">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"  (click)="onSelected(products)" >Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This includes the product group component template, but not the component itself. Can you post the component code?

Comment: here is my all components

Comment: Do you have a specific question about this code? Or does it just not work? If the later, could you provide a plunker with the code we could run?

Comment: No it is not working. i want to show the related product for a specific pincode. just want to know how i will do it and how i will store my pincode and product.

Comment: I guess you want that your pincode component to be a child component, then you actually need to put the child tag in your parent. Check this one out, where is use case for what you seem to want: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child  notice the template tag in that example in the parent template: `<hero-child></hero-child>`